# selecting entries that are referenced in one of multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have four tables:

```
company
id | name

order
number | company_id

quote
number | company_id

invoice
number | company_id
```

I want to get the list of companies that are referenced in any of the three (i.e., exclude companies that aren't in any).

I wrote this query:

```
select c.id, c.name from company c
left outer join order o on o.company_id = c.id
left outer join quote q on q.company_id = c.id
left outer join invoice i on i.company_id = c.id
where o.number is not null or q.number is not null or i.number is not null
```

But the `order`, `quote`, and `invoice` tables are quite large. So the `join` causes the query to run forever (one join is O(m*n), three joins is O(m*n*p*q)).

I COULD run this query basically three times with only one join on each query (O(m*n) + O(m*p) + O(m*q)), but I'm hoping for a more optimal solution.

This is for Oracle

Comment: The danger in how you've approached it is that the three tables are each likely to include multiple rows per company. So company 1 might have 5 quotes, 2 orders, and 2 invoices, for a total of 20 rows (5*2*2) returned just for that one company. It's not the underlying size of the tables that is causing the poor performance, but the fact that the company may appear several times in any one, and these duplicates are then magnified onto subsequent joins.

Comment: @Steve Right, I understand that. I knew that even before even writing the query, actually. I was just trying to show my approach to the solution to illustrate why I was stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join to a subquery which does a union of the three order tables:

```
SELECT
    c.id, c.name
FROM company c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT company_id FROM order
    UNION
    SELECT company_id FROM quote
    UNION
    SELECT company_id FROM invoice
) t
    ON c1.id = t.company_id
```

The union queries should automatically remove duplicate `company_id`, such that only distinct companies which are present in any of the three tables should be in the result set of that subquery.  The inner join then filters off any companies which were not present at all.